# Jacskon XML serialization of a list

Tags: java, xml, jackson, serialization

EDIT: I am trying to serialise to XML markup from Java objects.

I am struggling to serialise some XML from a List of size N of Integers using Jackson.

I want to output the following XML from a list of integers of variable length [9, 2, ... , 7].

```
<tagName>
   <thing1>9</thing1>
   <thing2>2</thing2>
   ...
   <thingN>7</thingN>
<tagName>
```

I can't find any resource on here for dealing with deserialising lists.

The closest I have managed to get is

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "thing")
private List<Integer> thingList;
```

And I can't figure out how to add a counter to the local name for each member of the list.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Not very clear: are you trying to serialize to the required markup or de-serialize to your class containing the `List`? Or both?

Comment: Maybe you should consider serialising as a map so you get `<thing><key>1</key><value>9</value><thing>`
Your xml shouldn't really carry values in its tags.

Comment: @Ben Your Xml contain unknown properties to the Jackson.
<thing1>9</thing1>
   <thing2>2</thing2>
thing1 , thing2 ..thingN are not equal properties. You have a workaround to do before parsing it from the xml.

Comment: @Ben Thomas, I add a sample solution below Check if it working to you?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts This XML format is required by a third party API, over which I have no cotrol

Comment: @PrathibhaChiranthana I am trying to produce that XML, not parse it.

Comment: @BenThomas whats actually yo need to do.
Do you need to parse this XML in to list or you need to convert the list into XML.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Ok Now I got your problem. So We I tried It with Jsoup library and find below code snippet for your work.

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                int [] array={1,2,3,4,5};
                TagName name = new TagName();
               //initialize the TagName object
               for (int a=0;a<array.length;a++) {
                    name.setThingList(array[a]);
               }

                XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
                try {
                    //get object as a string
                    String value = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(name);
                   //First you need to parse the xml
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(value, "", Parser.xmlParser());
                  //get tagname object
                    Element tagname = doc.getElementsByTag("tagname").first();
                  //get tagname's children which are thing
                    Elements childs = tagname.children();
                    for (int a = 0; a < childs.size(); ) {
                       //rename their tagname
                        childs.get(a).tagName("thing" + ++a);
                    }
                    System.out.println(tagname);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

```html
<tagname>
 <thing1>
  1
 </thing1>
 <thing2>
  2
 </thing2>
 <thing3>
  3
 </thing3>
 <thing4>
  4
 </thing4>
 <thing5>
  5
 </thing5>
</tagname>
```

```
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "xml")
    public class TagName {

        public ArrayList<Integer> getThingList() {
            return thingList;
        }

        public void setThingList(Integer thing) {

            this.thingList.add(thing);

        }

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "tagname")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "thing")
        private ArrayList<Integer> thingList = new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

Comment: such text manipulation is dangerous. it is better to solve the problem while parsing the XML or after parsing.

Comment: You can use a secure way to
String input = "<tagName>" +
                "   <thing1>9</thing1>" +
                "   <thing2>2</thing2>" +
                "   <thingN>7</thingN>" +
                "</tagName>";
        input = input.replaceAll("g[0-9]>", "g>");//Remove number in the thing tag
        input = input.replaceAll("gN>", "g>");//Rename thingN tag to thing

Do this?

But how do we solve the problem after it occurs when parsing. We have to do it before I think

Comment: Using this code ```@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "tagname")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "thing")
        private ArrayList<Integer> thingList = new ArrayList<>();```
worked GREAT for me to name a list with one value while keeping the items within the list with a different value.